# React and google-maps-react. Not displaying InfoWindow

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I am using React and google-maps-react library for a project. I am trying to display InfoWindows for each of the markers. But it is not working. I have looked at the documentation as well as GitHub issues for this and have no been able to find a solution.

Here is the code

```
import React from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker, InfoWindow } from "google-maps-react";

import { API_GOOGLE_MAPS } from "../config";

const mapStyles = {
    width: "100%",
    height: "100%"
};

export class GoogleMap extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let markers = this.props.vendors
            ? this.props.vendors.map((vendor, index) => {
                  return (
                      <Marker
                          key={index}
                          id={index}
                          position={{
                              lat: vendor.Latitude,
                              lng: vendor.Longitude
                          }}
                          onClick={() => console.log("You clicked me!")}
                      >
                          <InfoWindow
                              position={{
                                  lat: vendor.Latitude,
                                  lng: vendor.Longitude
                              }}
                              visible={true}
                          >
                              <div id={vendor.Latitude}>hello</div>
                          </InfoWindow>
                      </Marker>
                  );
              })
            : null;

        return (
            <Map google={this.props.google} zoom={13} style={mapStyles} initialCenter={this.props.mapCenter}>
                {markers ? markers : null}
            </Map>
        );
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    vendors: state.app.vendors,
    mapCenter: state.app.mapCenter
});

const WrappedContainer = GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: API_GOOGLE_MAPS
})(GoogleMap);

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(WrappedContainer);
```

The maps displays all the markers, but not the InfoWindow. I am probably doing this wrong. How can I get the InfoWindow to display for the markers?

Here is a [picture](https://i.imgur.com/CPv9sne.png)

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like support for InfoWindow as a prop child of Marker was a [pull request](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react/pull/277) that was merged into version 2.0.3 which isn't live yet. The latest NPM version as of this date (1 September 2019) is 2.0.2.

What you can do is open an info window when a marker is clicked by placing the infowindow at the same level of the markers and then connect it to each marker depending on the one that is clicked.

Have a look at the following [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hermann-5ehs7) which is based off of the demo. Sample code below.

```
      <Map
        google={this.props.google}
        onClick={this.onMapClicked}
        zoom={13}
      >
        <Marker
          name="Marker 1"
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          position={{ lat: 37.778519, lng: -122.40564 }}
        />

        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
        >
          <div>
            <h4>Hello</h4>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
```

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks. But I've noticed since you are updating state when you click on `<Marker />`, you will cause a re-render of the whole `<Map/>`. Makes it look buggy. Any solution?

Comment: Heya, can you clarify what you mean by buggy look please? This is the library's code, it's how it's implemented in the demo too, so in any case I'd assume there is no "solution" for intended behavior, or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Yes, to clarify. If you look closely at the demo, when you click on a marker, all the markers are very quickly re-rendering. This is most likely because the state of the component is changing to show/unshow the InfoWindow.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, i do see what you mean now and i'll be happy to help you find a solution although this would be an entire different question

Answer (score 0):

Here is a complete solution **InfoWindow** shows. i have also attached the link you can see for more understanding.. https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hermann-5ehs7

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper } from "google-maps-react";

export class MapContainer extends Component {
  state = {
    activeMarker: {},
    selectedPlace: {},
    showingInfoWindow: false
  };

  onMarkerClick = (props, marker) =>
    this.setState({
      activeMarker: marker,
      selectedPlace: props,
      showingInfoWindow: true
    });

  onInfoWindowClose = () =>
    this.setState({
      activeMarker: null,
      showingInfoWindow: false
    });

  onMapClicked = () => {
    if (this.state.showingInfoWindow)
      this.setState({
        activeMarker: null,
        showingInfoWindow: false
      });
  };

  render() {
    if (!this.props.loaded) return <div>Loading...</div>;

    return (
      <Map
        className="map"
        google={this.props.google}
        onClick={this.onMapClicked}
        style={{ height: "100%", position: "relative", width: "100%" }}
        zoom={13}
      >
        <Marker
          name="Marker 1"
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          position={{ lat: 37.778519, lng: -122.40564 }}
        />

        <Marker
          name="Marker 2"
          onClick={this.onMarkerClick}
          position={{ lat: 37.759703, lng: -122.428093 }}
        />

        <Marker name="Marker 3" onClick={this.onMarkerClick} />

        <InfoWindow
          marker={this.state.activeMarker}
          onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}
          visible={this.state.showingInfoWindow}
        >
          <div>
            <h4>{this.state.selectedPlace.name}</h4>
          </div>
        </InfoWindow>
      </Map>
    );
  }
}
export default GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: "",
  version: "3.38"
})(MapContainer);
```

[image]