# Google-maps-react marker not showing InfoWindow onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, ecmascript-6, google-maps-react

When I click the google maps marker, it registers the click but I cant appear to get the InfoWindow to appear after the state change.

Tried setting/reading from an updated state on click

'''react

```
import React from 'react';
import {Map, InfoWindow, Marker, GoogleApiWrapper} from 'google-maps-react'; 

export class BathroomMap extends React.Component{

constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        gmapsAPI: "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key="+ this.API_KEY +"&callback=initMap",
        center: {
            lat: 40.7367,
            lng: -73.9899
          },
        zoom: 15,
        showingInfoWindow: false,
        activeMarker: {},
        selectedPlace: {},
        infoWindowOpen: false,
    }

    this.handleToggleOpen = this.handleToggleOpen.bind(this);
}

handleToggleOpen = () => {
    console.log("Marker Clicked");
    this.setState({
       infoWindowOpen: !this.state.infoWindowOpen,
    });
}

render() {
    return (

            <Map google={window.google} zoom={14} initialCenter={this.state.center}>
                <Marker onClick={this.handleToggleOpen}
                    name={'Current location'} />
                <InfoWindow open={this.state.infoWindowOpen} onClose={this.onInfoWindowClose}>
                    <div>
                        <h1>Marker Info Placeholder</h1>
                    </div>
                </InfoWindow>
            </Map>

    );
}
}

BathroomMap = GoogleApiWrapper({
  apiKey: (/*Omitted*/)
})(BathroomMap)
```

'''

I expected google map marker with some sort of InfowWindow to appear but instead the infowWindowOpened returns undefined

Answer (score 0):

The [google-maps-react](https://github.com/fullstackreact/google-maps-react) documentation on InfoWindow says the following:

> The visibility of the `<InfoWindow />` component is controlled by a
>   visible prop. The visible prop is a boolean `(PropTypes.bool)` that
>   shows the `<InfoWindow />` when true and hides it when false.
>
> There are two ways how to control a position of the `<InfoWindow />`
>   component. You can use a `position` prop or connect the `<InfoWindow />`
>   component directly to an existing `<Marker />` component by using a
>   `marker` prop.

In your code implementation, you're missing a `visible` prop, and either a `position` prop or a `marker` prop. This is why your info window is not showing up.

My answer and linked [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quizzical-hermann-5ehs7) in related thread [React and google-maps-react. Not displaying InfoWindow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57666455/react-and-google-maps-react-not-displaying-infowindow) will hopefully help you.